# Using the rscopus::scopus_search, how can I run all the necessary searches given my API quota?

Tags: bibliography, scopus

The rscopus package takes one's API quota as an argument. However, would it be possible to chunk up the publication records, and finally return all the records together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a custom function I've written, called [`scopus_search_plus`](https://github.com/pablobernabeu/rscopus_plus).